# Stochastically removing edges from a complete graph; looking for info on this process

Tags: graph-theory, stochastic-processes

Given a complete graph of $n$ nodes and a time interval $T = \{t_1, \ldots, t_k\}$. Suppose each edge has a small probability $p$ of being removed from the graph at each time step and that this $p$ is the same for each edge and for each time step $t_i$. I am interested in the number of disconnected nodes in the graph over time, and am looking for more literature on this process (if there exists any). Specifically, I am interested in finding out if the number of disconnected nodes over time follows a specific distribution.

A quick Google search pointed me in the direction of [contact processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_process_(mathematics))
 but this does not seem to be what I want. Any information is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the Erdös-Renyi graph, it's essentially the complementary graph to yours. You should be able to apply similar techniques to determine distributions and limits. See e.g. the lectures of Hofstad on random graphs.

Comment: @Dominik your comment helped me find a lot more useful literature, thank you.